# More than one index of notation in a single document using nomencl

Tags: indexing

My thesis consists of two rather independent parts, and I'd like to include an index of notation for each part separately at the end of the whole document. Is this possible with the `nomencl` package?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you just want to how if it's possible or how it can be done? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently `nomencl` writes the index into the file `\jobname.nlo`, so if your file is `thesis.tex`, you will have `thesis.nlo`.  Thus if you want two indices, you need to rewrite this part of `nomencl`.  Namely:

1. Define the commands `\makenomenclatureA` and `\makenomenclatureB` that write two indices, say, `PartA.nlo` and `PartB.nlo`.
2. Define the similar commands `\printnomenclatureA` and `\printnomenclatureB`.
3. Put in the document

   ```
   \makenomenclatureA
   TEXT
   \renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenclature A}
   \printnomenclatureA

   \makenomenclatureB
   TEXT
   \renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenclature B}
   \printnomenclatureB
   ```
4. Run `pdflatex` and then

   ```
   makeindex -o PartA.nls -s nomencl.ist PartA.nlo
   makeindex -o PartB.nls -s nomencl.ist PartB.nlo
   ```
5. Run `pdflatex` again.

Now let us do (1) and (2).  We can take the definitions of `\makenomenclature` and `\printnomenclature` and modify them.  Here is the quick hack (copy the part between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makeatletter
\newwrite\@nomenclaturefile
\def\makenomenclatureA{%
  \closeout\@nomenclaturefile
  \openout\@nomenclaturefile=PartA\@outputfileextension
  \def\@nomenclature{%
    \@bsphack
    \begingroup
    \@sanitize
    \@ifnextchar[%
    {\@@@nomenclature}{\@@@nomenclature[\nomprefix]}}%
  \typeout{Writing nomenclature file PartA\@outputfileextension}%
  \let\makenomenclature\@empty}
\def\makenomenclatureB{%
  \closeout\@nomenclaturefile
  \openout\@nomenclaturefile=PartB\@outputfileextension
  \def\@nomlature{%push.relevant.stage.int
    \@bsphack
    \begingroup
    \@sanitize
    \@ifnextchar[%
    {\@@@nomenclature}{\@@@nomenclature[\nomprefix]}}%
  \typeout{Writing nomenclature file PartB\@outputfileextension}%
  \let\makenomenclature\@empty}
\def\printnomenclatureA{%
  \@ifnextchar[%
    {\@printnomenclatureA}{\@printnomenclatureA[\nomlabelwidth]}}
\def\@printnomenclatureA[#1]{%
  \nom@tempdim#1\relax
  \@input@{PartA\@inputfileextension}}
\def\printnomenclatureB{%
  \@ifnextchar[%
    {\@printnomenclatureB}{\@printnomenclatureB[\nomlabelwidth]}}
\def\@printnomenclatureB[#1]{%
  \nom@tempdim#1\relax
  \@input@{PartB\@inputfileextension}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{First}

\makenomenclatureA
\nomenclature{a}{Definition of a}
\nomenclature{b}{Definition of b}
\nomenclature{c}{Definition of c}

\renewcommand\nomname{Nomenclature A}
\printnomenclatureA

\section{Second}

\makenomenclatureB
\nomenclature{a'}{Definition of a'}
\nomenclature{b'}{Definition of b'}
\nomenclature{c'}{Definition of c'}

\renewcommand\nomname{Nomenclature B}
\printnomenclatureB

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Dear Boris, thank you very much for your effort and your fast reponse, your suggestion works fine and does precisely what I wanted!